# How to send/share a shared link from OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I uploaded a file to OneDrive from my application. The file was uploaded succesfully and I also got in my application a "shared link" to my file.

Now, my question is, how can I send automatically from my app to another user (identified by email, phone number or something else) this shared link ? Is OneDrive API giving support for this ?

Should I send this link using another provider such a separate email from a SMTP server, or using a SMS ?